# Dual state button algorithm in C

Tags: algorithm, c, embedded, device-driver

I wrote code for determining the push button state whether it is long pressed or not. This function is called by timer interrupt routine every 1ms.

But it seems really dumb. How can I make it shorter and more efficient according to both readability and professional rules? What should I add or change to get double Tap pressing information with this  code?

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{   
    /*button pressed and count*/
    if(!HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13))
    {
        usTick++;
    }
    /*not pressed*/
    else
    {
        if( usTick > 1000){
            ButtonState.PressedState = LongPressed;
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);       
            usTick = 0;
        }
        else if( usTick >350){
            ButtonState.PressedState = ShortPressed;
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);               
            usTick = 0;
        }               
        usTick = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is pin 13 connected to an interrupt?

Comment: no just a regular Input pin. I just enabled the timer interrupt in order to measure pressed time so that i can decide long or short pressing

Comment: Do you really have to poll here? Is there no way for you to receive an interrupt when the button is pressed *and* when it is released?

Comment: I didnt get it, how I can measure the pressed timing without timer interrupt?

Comment: Using interrupts for buttons is a very bad idea, unless you know exactly what you are doing. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646071/slight-delay-after-returning-from-interrupt/32647699#32647699

Answer (score 3):

> ... how can I make it shorter and more efficient according to both readability and professional rules?

Calling

```
usTick = 0;
```

is superfluous in the `else` branches sub-conditions. That can be rewritten like:

```
/*not pressed*/
else
{
    if( usTick > 1000){
        ButtonState.PressedState = LongPressed;
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);       
    }
    else if( usTick >350){
        ButtonState.PressedState = ShortPressed;
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);       
    }          
    // Calling those statements Once is enough here 
    usTick = 0;
}
```

Checking the minimum limit and reducing the whole sub-conditions with a ternary condition operator (as mentioned in [@David Isla's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/152381/52802)), the whole code could be boiled down to a few lines:

```
/*not pressed*/
else
{
    if( usTick > 350) {
         ButtonState.PressedState = usTick > 1000 ? LongPressed : ShortPressed;
         HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);       
    }
    usTick = 0;
}
```

---

> What should I add or change to get double Tap pressing information with this code?

You might consider to put any data updating operations into critical sections (or other non-interruptible code paths):

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{   
    /*button pressed and count*/
    if(!HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13))
    {
        START_CRITCAL_SECTION();
        usTick++;
        END_CRITCAL_SECTION();
    }
    /*not pressed*/
    else {
        START_CRITCAL_SECTION();
        if( usTick > 350) {
             ButtonState.PressedState = usTick > 1000 ? LongPressed : ShortPressed;
             HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);       
        }
        usTick = 0;
        END_CRITCAL_SECTION();
    }
}
```

where `START_CRITCAL_SECTION()` disables all interrupts, and `END_CRITCAL_SECTION()` reenables their former state.

This may help, that any co-routines or threads will always read consistent values for `ustick` or the `GPIO_PIN_5` state.

Comment: But you can just call `HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);` when `usTick` is greater to 350

Comment: @DavidIsla Yes, you're right about that, the logic won't be the same. Fixed it. I hope you're not bothered I've _"stolen"_ the ternary operator from your answer ;-) (gave your answer an upvote).

Comment: of course not! ;-)

Comment: I think I didn't ask my latest question clearly. Ok I got your answers. But I want to make this script more efficient. Let's assume we got 1 button. Until now I could determine short or long pressing. How can we understand double tap pressing besides long and short pressing?

Comment: @ree 1. C programs aren't _scripts_ 2. Define _"more efficient"_ from that context clearly please. Less code? Less blocking in interrupt routines? Or what else?

Comment: with this part of this code we could only understand whether long pressed or short right?
what if I want to add double tap pressing functionality to my button besides short and long pressing
How should I wrote the code about it?

Comment: @ree _"... double tap pressing ..."_ will be flying below the radar of that function using critical sections. For something like that, you'll need to measure times between button pressed, button released and button pressed again. I'm only reviewing the logic you've been presenting here. There's nothing more you can expect from Code Review.

Comment: @ree _"I think I didn't ask my latest question clearly. ..."_ So you essentially want someone to add that necessary code for the detection of _double pressing_? That's an off topic question at Code Review, sorry.

Comment: The conditional operator includes an implicit type promotion of `LongPressed` and `ShortPressed;` to `int`, which could potentially be a bug in some circumstances. In the worst case it becomes a dormant bug that only surfaces when the code is ported/compiler is changed. Always avoid implicit type promotions! Better solution: use `if-else`. Like in the original code...

Comment: "You might consider to put any data updating operations into critical sections" It would seem that the function is an ISR and on almost every MCU, ISRs cannot get interrupted. So this is rather pointless. A more valid concern is that `usTick` must be declared as `volatile` since it is shared between the caller and an ISR. For entirely different reasons: namely to avoid bugs caused by aggressive compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

Repeat `HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);` is a little bit ugly for me, that would be my approach:

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{   
    // Button pressed
    if(!READ_PIN_13)
    {
        usTick++;
    }
    else 
    {
        // Not pressed
        if( usTick > 350 )
        {
            ButtonState.PressedState = usTick > 1000 ? LongPressed : ShortPressed;
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);               
        }               
        usTick = 0;
    }
}
```